# How to access the contents of this collection in laravel/php

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am new to Laravel and doing a project to build a mini-social network app.I have a post model that has a relationship with the user model.
I have a Post page, where only the posts of the authenticated user and his/her friends will show. In my PostController, i queried for the friends of the authenticated user like so;

```
$friends = Auth::user()->friends();
```

Where the friends() object has earlier been defined in my friendable trait. That works well as shown in the screen shot.
I tried to query for the posts whose user_id is that of the authenticated user or that of the friends, like so

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $user->id)
               ->where('user_id', $friends->id)
               ->get();
```

but keep getting an error

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance…

The collection is shown as die-dumped on the screen-shot. How can I iterate over and get an array of the id’s of all the friends.
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you getting error on server-side ( i.e laravel ) or javascript side ( i.e on console) as your screenshot seems to be of browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$friends = Auth::user()->friends();
```

now the `$friends` is a collection, which contains a collection of users, please note that `$friends` does not contain a variable named `id` rather the each item in collection(The User object) contains an id.

This is where you get the error - `->where('user_id', $friends->id)`(here `$friends` have no id )

so first we take out all the ids of friends, and then take the posts which are made by the friends.

```
$friends = Auth::user()->friends();
$friends_id = $friends->pluck('id'); //we have all friends id as an array

$posts = Post::where('user_id', $user->id)
               ->whereIn('user_id', $friends_id)
               ->get();
```