# Access collection instance as javascript variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to send collection of following Query:

```
 $monthly_report_chart = DB::table("transactions")
        ->select(DB::raw("Date(updated_at) as today"),DB::raw("SUM(collected_today) as sum"))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(updated_at)'))
        ->where(DB::raw('Month(updated_at)'),'=',$month)
        ->get();
```

And i want to access the collection in javascript like this :

```
{!! json_encode($monthly_report_chart->today) !!}
```

But it throws following Error :

> Property [today] does not exist on this collection instance

How do access collection instance in javascript? 
Thanks!

Comment: You should try to access the property on a model, not on collection.

Comment: Can you share what collection return ? just dd($monthly_report_chart) in your controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48416095/2693543

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your collection has today property you can use pluck on collection. 
E.g

```
{!! json_encode($monthly_report_chart->pluck('today')) !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `first()`:

```
$monthly_report_chart = DB::table("transactions")
    ->select(DB::raw("Date(updated_at) as today"),DB::raw("SUM(collected_today) as sum"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(updated_at)'))
    ->where(DB::raw('Month(updated_at)'),'=',$month)
    ->first();
```

Or `loop` through your collections and access `individual` ones:

```
@foreach($monthly_report_chart as $report_chart)
     {!! json_encode($report_chart->today) !!}
@endforeach
```