# Displaying image from database in grid - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have my image `path` in my database and now, i am trying to get the image into my html grid. But when i try to fetch the image, i get an error

> Property [path] does not exist on this collection instance.

But then, there is path attribute in my table in the database.  Has it got to be an error from my models? My model seems right to me. Anyway what am i not doing right here, please?

Thanks for your concern

**HTML**

```
<figure>
    <div class="snipcart-item block">
       <div class="snipcart-thumb">
           <a  href="{{ route('product.view', $product->slug)}}"><img src="{{$product->images->path}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
           <p>{{$product->name}}</p>
           <h4>GH₵ {{ number_format($product->price,2) }} </h4>
       </div>
       <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details">
         <form action="#" method="post">
           <fieldset>

           </fieldset>
         </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</figure>
```

**Image**

```
public function products()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

**Product_images**

```
public function images()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

Comment: show you table `images`

Comment: you may have error in relation

Comment: What is your Laravel version?

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari, laravel 5

Comment: Images returns a `Collection`, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. You need to loop through all of the existing images.

Comment: @fab, i am actually looping through like     `@foreach($products as $product)` but i didn't show the part of the code

Comment: First, assuming your second model relationship should be `Product` instead of `Image`, you defined a `One-To-Many` relationship. Therefore, each product can have multiple images.

Comment: Try to foreach image like: `@foreach($product->images as $image) 
   <img src="{{$image->path}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /> 
@endforeach
`

Comment: @HirenGohel, i get this error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string`

Comment: Try this: `@foreach($product->images as $image) <img src="{{ asset($image->path) }}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />`

Comment: @HirenGohel, another error `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string,`

Comment: See first method is working for me which gives you `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string`! It'll gives error because you don't have an image or null path! Try to make `if` condition and then test it! It'll work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a `foreach` as it's give you a collection.

Hence, try to display it like:

```
@foreach($product->images as $image) 
   @if($image->path)
     <img src="{{ $image->path }}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
   @else
      <p>No image to display!</p>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Hope this will helps you!

Comment: the condition is not working. it still throws the error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,`

Comment: Updated answer, check now.

Comment: it is suppose to be `   @if(!$image->path)` that works. it shows the text `No image display`

Comment: Then your image path is not saved OR it's not true OR that image is not present to that path! Because this is working in my project!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the Product model hasMany Images.
In order to reach the path property you should do this:

```
@foreach($product->images as $image) 
    {{$image->path}} 
@endforeach
```

Or do this in your Product Model and change your database structure

```
public function image()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Image::class);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your path does not any issue, the following is the correct way to display an image in Laravel blade template.

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('directory/name_of_image_file.file_format')}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have field `path` in DB `images`
You code must be:

```
<img src="{{$product->images->[you field in Db images]}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: I see `<img src="{{$product->images->path}}"` in his code?

Comment: i have a table called `product_images` which field `path`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a  href="{{ route('product.view', $product->slug)}}">
   <img src="{{$product->images->first()->path}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
</a>
```

`$product->images` is a collection, you need to get the image out of the collection. for now I have used the `first()` which will fetch the first image, you may want to loop through the collection depending on your scenario. You may want to read about an answer have written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48416095/2693543)

Comment: i get an error saying `trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: in this case your images collection seems to empty, can you `dd($product)` and show us? please show `dd($product->images)` also

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<figure>
    <div class="snipcart-item block">
       <div class="snipcart-thumb">
           <a  href="{{ route('product.view', $product->slug)}}"><img src="{{$product->images->first()->path}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
           <p>{{$product->name}}</p>
           <h4>GH₵ {{ number_format($product->price,2) }} </h4>
       </div>
       <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details">
         <form action="#" method="post">
           <fieldset>

           </fieldset>
         </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</figure>
@endforeach
```